# Filtering through two foreign key relationships in django

Tags: django

I have three models:

```
class Studio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Studio", max_length=30, unique=True)

class Film(models.Model):
    studio = models.ForeignKey(Studio, verbose_name="Studio")
    name = models.CharField("Film Name", max_length=30, unique=True)

class Actor(models.Model):
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film, verbose_name="Film")
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=30, unique=True)
```

I want to query Actor to see if a specific combination of Studio, Film, and Actor exists in the database.  I know how to check if Actor exists.  I know how to filter for Actor name and Film name.  Is there a one-line method to query for Actor name AND Film name AND Studio name (two traversals up the foreign key chain)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Actor.objects.filter(name="actorname",film__name="filmname", film__studio__name="studioname")
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 6):

Just keep chaining `__` to keep the traversal going:

```
Actor.objects.filter(film__studio__name='Something')
```

Answer (score 3):

Something along the line of

`Actor.objects.filter(name='foo', film__name='bar', film__studio__name='baz')`